# Getting the next Item in a queryset

Tags: python, django, web, view, voting

Here's a snippet from Voting web project, and I'm trying to get the next category after voting...

When the user has successfully voted, I want the page to redirect to next category... What I did was to get the id of that category then save a variable as next_category having the id of the original category incremented by one(next_category = category.id + 1).

But as you Know Django doesn't make id's strictly serially so if I've deleted a category before, lets say cat 5 and i have cat1 cat2 thought to cat10, when it gets to cat4, it'll have issues

The Nominees view gives the page for the particular category and the Voting view is the form processing view.
Hope its explanatory enough.

```
@login_required
def Nominees(request, category_id):
    categories = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
    next_category = categories.id +1
    college_id = categories.College.id
    if lastday < today:
        messages.info(request, "Window closed")
    context = {'categories':categories, 'college_id':college_id, 'lastday':lastday, 'today':today,'next_category':next_category}
    return render(request, 'nomination/contestants.html', context )

def Voting(request):
    if request.method == "POST": 
        vote_user = request.POST.get('vote_user')
        vote_contestant = request.POST.get('vote_contestant')
        vote_category = request.POST.get('vote_category')
        next_category = request.POST.get('next_cat')
        vote_college = request.POST.get('vote_college')
        college = College.objects.get(pk=int(vote_college))
        college_id = college.id
        nex = int(next_category)-1
        try:
            Vote.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id, category_id=vote_category)[0]
            messages.error(request, "You've already voted")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('nomination:nominees', args=(vote_category,)))
        except(IndexError, Vote.DoesNotExist):
            if lastday < today:
                messages.error(request, "Too late")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('nomination:nominees', args=(vote_category,)))
            else:
                new_vote = Vote(contestant_id=vote_contestant, category_id=vote_category, college_id=vote_college, user_id=vote_user)
                new_vote.save()
                messages.success(request, "Successfully voted!!")
                try:
                    categories = college.category_set.filter(id=next_category, College_id=college_id)[nex]
                    category_id=categories.id
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('nomination:nominees', args=(category_id,)))
                except (IndexError, Category.DoesNotExist):
                    categories = college.category_set.first()
                    category_id = categories.id
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('nomination:categories', args=(college_id,)))
```

I would also appreciate it if I could get a better way of doing this, like maybe using the next function which I've tried but still it's giving me issues.

Comment: You'd be better off making a voting collection model with references to categories, you shouldn't rely on id's being sequential

Comment: @Sayse Could you please elaborate on how I go about that, Cuz I don't get, I would appreciate a code snippet...thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

So just in case some are still trying to figure it out I later found another way, I converted the queryset into a list and used the index function:

```
def Nominees(request, category_id):
    category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
    college_id = category.College.id
    college = College.objects.get(id=college_id)
    categories = list(college.category_set.all())
    next_category = (categories.index(category)) + 1
    if lastday < today:
        messages.info(request, "Window closed")
    context = {'categories':category, 'college_id':college_id, 'lastday':lastday, 'today':today,'next_category':next_category}
    return render(request, 'nomination/contestants.html', context )

def Next(request):
    next_category = request.POST.get('next_cat')
    college_id = request.POST.get('college_id')
    college = College.objects.get(id=int(college_id))
    nex = int(next_category)
    nxcate = list(college.category_set.all())
    if request.method =="POST":
        try:
            name = nxcate[nex]
            nxcat = college.category_set.filter(Name=name)[0]
            print(nxcat, nxcat.id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('nomination:nominees', args=(name.id,)))
        except IndexError:
            name = nxcate[0]
            print('\n',name)
            messages.info(request,"Thank you for voting!!!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('nomination:categories', args=(college_id,)))
```